# Como retornar token no registro de usuário no adonis?

Tags: node.js, adonisjs

Estou criando uma api de registro de usuário e gostaria de retornar além do usuário registrado, o token jwt.

Atualmente esta são minhas funções:

```
initializeCreate( {request} ){
    const data = request.only(["username", "password", "permission", "status"])
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        user.create(data, function(err, resp, body) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(JSON.parse(body))
            }
        })
    })
}

createUser({ auth }){

var initializePromise = initializeCreate();
initializePromise.then(function(result) {
    const token = await auth.attempt(result.username, result.password)
    return token     
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
})}
```

Suponho que eu devo esperar o evento `User.create()` terminar pra depois realizar o `auth.attempt` por isso criei a promise, porém como seria a melhor forma de fazer isso? Atualmente estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> Unexpected token const token = await auth.attempt(result.username,
>   result.password)